# How NOT to print sheet name and page number in OpenOffice.org Calc?

Tags: printer, openoffice, openoffice-calc

When I print a spreadsheet in OpenOffice.org Calc (latest version), it keeps adding the name of my current sheet to the top, and a page number to the bottom of my print out.

How do I turn this off?

P.S. I am running it on Mac OS X 10.6.4 Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Go to "Format" , "Page...", Header/Footer to set up the pages how you want them

Edit 2015
I´m using Libre Office these days but a similar set of commands works there too. I´m suprised this answer still gets so many hits, glad it helps!!

Comment: This answer should NOT be getting this many hits, its proof of a poor UI design.